# Move picturebox a really small distance

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to move a picturebox under 0.6.
This works:

```
pbxMapPlayer.Left += 0.6
```

But I want this:

```
pbxMapPlayer.Left += 0.4
```

Comment: So you're trying to move a picture box 0.4 pixels? Google luck with that. 1 pixel is the minimum. `Left += 0.6` works because it is rounded up to 1.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and that will not compile, which tells you Something Is Wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that. When you increment the [PictureBox.Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.controls.picturebox.left.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property by `0.6` it actually gets incremented by `1` because the property is an integer and the += operator expects integer arguments. The `0.6` numeral gets rounded to `1`. When you increment by `0.4` it gets rounded to `0` and that's why you see no movement as you are actually incrementing by `0`.